# Is a recap of the welcome wagon coming?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, welcoming

In the last couple of months Stack Exchange has undertaken significant effort to make the network more welcoming. From a regular user's perspective, we can only see the internal consequences and ripple effects this has had.

I was re-reading [Tim Post's Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373227/5389107) about the science behind what led to determining the necessity of the welcoming push.

In this post it is mentioned that Stack Exchange now employs highly skilled data scientists that seem to have a finger on the pulse of whether or not the efforts are paying off.

I'd be interested if the trend and numbers on this have seen a significant change with the welcoming push and in which direction. Has the initiative worked so far? How is Stack Exchange measuring this? Are there any particular areas that yet need more work?

**Edit 15.10.2019:**

It's been a full year now, it doesn't look like a response is forthcoming

Comment: Not answering because I don't have an answer _yet_. There are numbers, and they are moving, but we need to be sure we understand what's moving them and why. It might be another month or two before we have enough data to put solid theory out, but I'm pinging Julia to see if she'd be interested in say a monthly .. "It's network data science time with Julia!" thing here. Stay tuned.

Comment: @TimPost I have a feeling seeing the effects of what is being worked on first hand would to well to quell some of the fear and concerns over the whole initiative and inspire some confidence in established users who are anxious to see SE do well. Thanks for taking time to respond to my post :)

Comment: Definitely, I agree. We're at an awkward point where it's difficult to define clear KPI-oriented goals in the absence of knowing what's _possible_ in a community of this (unprecedented) size that's _largely_ self-governing. That's why I'm very careful when talking about things like the attrition rate, because _how_ we measure that matters just as much as the measurement itself, and we don't base strategy off of stuff we're not sure of yet, so it's hard to produce _public_ artifacts or even a solid roadmap at this point [1/3].

Comment: [2/3] However, I think there's stuff that we can share as we progress, but there's going to be a giant "We're sharing this for the sake of sharing it, don't shake your fists if decisions don't seem to reflect it yet" and that sort of thing.

Comment: [3/3] In other words, I think there's a substantial part of the community that would love to see all of this 'done and over with', and we're nowhere close to that, which ... well, we have to be careful to set up scenarios where we know we'll be at passionate odds with some folks _and have no other answers_. Quiet is, sometimes, the best strategy in those cases. But we'll see what we can do.

Comment: It's going to be interesting to see if there's a dip in the metrics where established users simply ignore the "new contributor" thing and go back to their previous behaviour.

Comment: adblock facilitates that behavior quite well

Comment: it's been a month @TimPost

Comment: @JeffAtwood would this count as follow-up: [Data science time! November 2018 and CORRELATIONS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376259/839601)

Comment: Note about bounty placed 10/5/19: The [company's description page](https://stackoverflow.com/company) says: "2018: Welcome Wagon launches, as our data scientists, developers, long-term community managers, and UX specialists evolve our Code of Conduct, commenting, and other features to make the site more welcoming, diverse, and inclusive."

Comment: It is important to add a new extension to this question asking: is stack exchange studying the welcomingness of existing users in aggressively thinking and pushing their policy to make the new users feel welcoming. In lieu of making new users onboard, is SE even trying to make exisitng users exist and reinforce trust in them?

Comment: @Jeff now it's a year. And see what happened to Stack Exchange. I'm really sorry to see the good thing you created destroyed from within in such a horrible way. If there's any chance you can buy your place back, pull some strings, etc... now it's the time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's no longer relevant

Comment: It has been a year @JeffAtwood

Comment: @Magisch I honestly fail to understand how it's off topic or no longer relevant, specially that a question asked  today was closed because it's a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @gdoron I can't self delete because someone answered it. This question was asked in a very different time when I still had more hope in processes going on. If you want to gripe about how they've done nothing but talk and then do nothing for months now, there's around 200 topics open on that matter.

Comment: and exactly who would believe whatever they posted at this point anyway?

Answer (score 41):

**A full year** passed since that "1 or 2 months" @TimPost mentioned.

You can clearly say, they don't want to share the numbers and I can only assume, they are bad and damaged the site and its communities.

Comment: No point speculating, we're in a different time with different problems now, and a blog post from 2018 is the least of our current concerns.

Comment: @Magisch I think it's all related. All their actions recently ignored the community opinion and refused to even share details and numbers. This is just another example, where even the co-founder of the company (@Jeff Atwood) didn't get an answer to his question (or at least, a public one). Answering this question is another step required to restore trust from the community.

Comment: why would anyone trust anything they publish regardless

Comment: @SomeoneWhoUsedToCare On the positive side: The data is available. **Assuming** that the raw data has not been tampered with, one can inspect it. And actually, I started diving deeper into the data dumps from the surveys. Until now, I could not confirm the claims that have been made in some of the "data science" blog posts, but of course, that **does not mean that they are wrong**. It might only mean that (I'm not a proper data scientist, and) they didn't publish the process of how they conducted their Chi-Squared-Test and how they derived the p-Values that they published...

Comment: [*"Lies, damned lies, and statistics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics)