# Q&A activity over the last month

Tags: discussion, analytics

Over the last month, on some of the sites I visit regularly there seems to be a marked decrease in new questions and answers.

I personally have not noticed as much on work related sites, like dba.se but on personal hobby and development sites, there seems to be a sharp decline.

Is it possible to define what the level of post activity has been in the last month compared to other related times (i.e. same month last year, last year overall)?

Comment: Users with enough rep can see those stats, best to ask on the individual stack you are interested in where such users exist.

Comment: Related: [Are other sites (besides MSE) growing inactive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336861/are-other-sites-besides-mse-growing-inactive)

Comment: See also samcarter's answer to this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336919/i-feel-that-lately-the-answers-to-my-questions-on-stack-exchange-are-low-quality

Comment: Similar: [All localized Stack Overflows seem to suffer from a decline to some degree. Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336925/282094).